# Динамическое создание id(String) для View элементов

Tags: java, android-studio

Есть задача, где неизвестно конечное количество `view` элементов , в `xml` разметке `id` указываются в тексте, программно можно только `int Id` создавать, так же можно делать заранее готовые `id` в папке `res/values` , но поскольку количество элементов варьируется от 40 до бесконечности условно, как создавать программно `id` так же как и в `xml` в `String`

Answer (score 1):

Динамически задать `id` для `View` можно только типа `int`, потому как класс *R.java*, содержащий идентификаторы ресурсов, может содержать только константы типа `int`, например:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class dimen {
        public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
        public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int main=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class mipmap {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f060000;
    }
    public static final class style {
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f070000;
    }
}
```

Идентификаторы представлений имеют тип int ([см. документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#IDs)):

```
Views may have an integer id associated with them.
```

А то, что в layout-файлах вы видите строки, например,  `android:id="@+id/first_next_btn"` - это всего лишь **ИМЯ** идентификатора, а в *R.java* файле этот идентификатор всё равно будет иметь тип `int`:

```
public static final int first_next_btn=0x7f0d0075;
```

Поэтому задать `id` другого типа в принципе невозможно. Но Вы можете вместо установки `id` воспользоваться методом `setTag`, позволяющим устанавливать дополнительную информацию, которая может быть связана с `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно делать так:

```
private static final AtomicInteger nextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

public static int generateId() {
    for (;;) {
        final int id = nextGeneratedId.get();
        int temp = id + 1;
        if (temp > 0x00FFFFFF) temp = 1;
        if (nextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, temp)) {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Также можно создать *res/values/ids.xml* и там заранее определить значения:

```
<item name="first_id" type="id"/>
```

Comment: Мне нужно что бы было именно имя , не цифры то есть id= "idView"

Comment: @Александр не понял. Имеется в виду чтобы можно было получить id путём обращения к xml файлу по имени? R.id.name

Comment: В xml рахметке android:id="@id/Blabla" я хочу програмнно создавать чтобы айдишник так же указывался буквами , а не цыфрами

Comment: @Александр обновил ответ. То что вы хотите, динамически сделать не знаю как. По сути эти имена- это параметры name в xml-разметке и они всё равно хранят в себе те же самые числа, которые вы так не хотите использовать. Сделайте массив из чисел, используя первый способ из ответа. Для использования из xml разметки используйте второй способ.

Comment: Да ,  я вас понял , спасибо